# manner in which duties were performed

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese

From [Criminal Justice Act Guidelines](http://www.wvsd.uscourts.gov/criminal-justice-act-cja-guidelines), on lawyer compensation:

> Determining Fair Compensation:
>   After establishing that a case is extended or complex, the approving 
>   judicial officer should determine if excess payment is necessary to provide 
>   fair compensation.  The following criteria, among others, may be useful in 
>   this regard:
>   - responsibilities involved measured by the magnitude and importance of the case;
>   - **manner in which duties were performed**;
>   - knowledge, skill, efficiency, professionalism, and judgment required of and used by counsel;
>   - nature of counsel’s practice and injury thereto;
>   - any extraordinary pressure of time or other factors under which services were rendered;
>   - and any other circumstances relevant and material to a determination of a fair and reasonable fee.

I'm not 100% sure of the meaning of the bolded phrase. Does it mean "Was the lawyer up to the task" (performing his duties in a proper manner or maybe even with enhanced vigor"? (I guess this is the meaning)

Or, does it mean "the character, the nature of the effort the lawyer had to exert to complete the task"? (hard, excessively demanding work, requiring advanced skills, etc.)

Or maybe it means, per *mplungjan*'s suggestion, "did he behave correctly, did he not intimidate someone, fake evidence, drive to interviews in taxies from out of state claiming expences"? (A sense I've totally overlooked, thanks, mplungjan!)

Comment: I would think the manner in this case means "did he behave correctly, did not intimidate someone, fake evidence, drive to interviews in taxies from out of state claiming expences"

Comment: Oh, I've overlooked this sense! Thank you, @mplungjan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wide range of approaches to almost any legal representation. The lawyer could be

> - cursory in his approach, uncommitted and doing the absolute minimum (or even less than what is needed)
> - thorough and doing what is needed, but nothing more
> - diligent and performing extra (but reasonable) tasks to ensure good rerprentation for his client
> - no holds barred, throwing everything including the kitchen sink at the project, overstaffing, running up time and expense beyond what is reasonable to accomplish a favorable outcome

And everything in between.

Courts tend to favor the third approach (and to a lesser degree, the second) and weigh that in deciding what is appropriate compensation.

There is no question that, if a lawyer behaves badly, a court would weigh that in reducing his compensation, as @mplungjan suggests.  However, most courts take the view that bad behavior is *not* to be expected, so that it is not usually a factor in the analysis

Answer (score 1):

I would consider

> did he behave correctly, did not intimidate someone, fake evidence, drive to interviews in taxies from out of state claiming extraordinary expenses